# Spy behavior-subject and apply .pipe

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, observable, karma-jasmine

I am running Units test for my component when a try to mock one attribute of type BehaviorSubject on my service, I received this error. "TypeError: Cannot read property 'pipe' of undefined".

I tried to mock one attribute as BehaviorSubject from my service in my component,

component.ts

```
export class ShowFiltersComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    private _unsubscribeAll: Subject<any>;
    filterSelected = [];
    constructor(
        private _chr: ChangeDetectorRef,
        private _pmService: PMService
    ) {
        this._unsubscribeAll = new Subject();
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this._pmService.onFilterShowSelected
            .pipe(takeUntil(this._unsubscribeAll))
            .subscribe(res => {
                this.filterSelected = res;
                this._chr.detectChanges();
            });
    }
    ngOnDestroy(): void {
        // Unsubscribe from all subscriptions
        this._unsubscribeAll.next();
        this._unsubscribeAll.complete();
    }
}
```

pmService.service.ts

```
export class PMService {

    _onFilterShowSelected: BehaviorSubject<any>;

    constructor(private _http: HttpClient) {
      this._onFilterShowSelected = new BehaviorSubject({});
    }

    get onFilterShowSelected(): BehaviorSubject<any> {
        return this._onFilterShowSelected;
    }
....
}
```

component.spect.ts

```
describe("ShowFiltersComponent", () => {
    let component: ShowFiltersComponent;
    let service: PatientManagementService;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<ShowFiltersComponent>;
    let httpMock: HttpClient;


    beforeEach(async(() => {
        const sp = spyOnProperty(
            new PMService(httpMock),
            "onFilterShowSelected",
            "get"
        ).and.returnValue(of({}));
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],

            declarations: [ShowFiltersComponent],
            imports: [HttpClientModule],
            providers: [
                {
                    provide: PMService,
                    useValue: sp
                }
            ]
        }).compileComponents();
    }));

    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ShowFiltersComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
    });

    it("should create", () => {
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

Comment: spyOnProperty() doesn't return the object containing the property. Create a PMService, then spyOnProperty, then use the created PMService in the providers.

Comment: upps I saw it, i updated the code
```
const sp = jasmine.createSpyObj("PMService", [
            "onFilterShowSelected"
        ]);

        sp.onFilterShowSelected.and.returnValue(of([]));
```

Comment: That creates an object with a **method** named onFilterShowSelected.

Comment: @Rotceh Did u try my suggested approach ?

Answer (score 0):

I would take a different approach and create a `stub` something like:

```
describe("ShowFiltersComponent", () => {
    let component: ShowFiltersComponent;
    let service: PatientManagementService;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<ShowFiltersComponent>;
    let httpMock: HttpClient;


    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
            declarations: [ShowFiltersComponent],
            imports: [HttpClientModule],
            providers: [
                {
                    provide: PMService,
                    useClass: PMServiceStub
                }
            ]
        }).compileComponents();
    }));

    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ShowFiltersComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
    });

    it("should create", () => {
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });
});


class PMServiceStub{
    get onFilterShowSelected(): BehaviorSubject<any> {
        return of({
           // ur desired object
        });
    }
}
```

**On side note**, rather than exposing the entire `BeahaviorSubject`  (which allows that component to access `next()`), you can return it as `.asObservable()` which doesn't allow to call `next()` unless explicitly such method is called by the component. Its just a good practice similar to `get` and `set`

```
 get onFilterShowSelected(): BehaviorSubject<any> {
        return this._onFilterShowSelected.asObservable();
    }
```